# SwiftUI bug with ScrollView appearance to the scene

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui, scrollview

I have problem in SwiftUI. I created ScollView and post into some Views. (News Articles). When i launch app - ScrollView and content inside appears in dioganal way, like animation. But i need to launch app and get static ScrollView with views inside it, without any movements.

Also the same problem occurred when i open sheet view with ScrollView and Text Blocks inside. It also appers first 0.3s like dioganaly way. But how can i achive static ? Thank you all )

Place i use sheet controller (Also this block in ScrollView)

```
ScrollView{
   ArticlePreView(image: "one", category: "Category", heading: "Header", author: "some text").onTapGesture {
                        self.showingDetail.toggle()
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                        Home()
                    }

}
```

[Image to understand](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VD6usIYSdEADNCV-rw9j4-GLmT4yQ315/view?usp=sharing)
[Video of problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OieGd_kFoDBFWFC6I_4fTOe0Pog2GqkN/view?usp=sharing)

And this is place of my sheet controller

```
ScrollView() {

            VStack {

                HStack {

                    Text("Soem long title")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)

                    Spacer()


                    Button(action: {

                    }) {

                        HStack {


                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)


                        }

                            .padding()
                    }
                        .background(
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.neuBackground)
                        )
                        .shadow(color: .dropShadow, radius: 15, x: 10, y: 10)
                        .shadow(color: .dropLight, radius: 15, x: -10, y: -10)


                }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 35)
                    .padding(.top, 25)


                Text("long text")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    .padding(.top, 20)

                Text("long text")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    .padding(.top, 20)

                Text("long text")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    .padding(.top, 20)

                Text("long text")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    .padding(.top, 20)

                Spacer(minLength: 50)


            }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
```

Comment: No one can anwser how to fix ? I have this bug in ScollView in all my projects!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using

```
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
.fixedSize()
```

SwiftUI is not adaptive